# Cookie being passed to client, but not being saved in browser

Tags: reactjs, cookies, flask, redux

I am getting cookie in Network as shown in below screen

[image]

but in browser this is showing blank

[image]

Front-end Code REACT

```
  signIn: (username, password) =>
    axios
      .post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/login', {
        data: {
          Username: username,
          Password: password,
        },
      })
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          console.log('sign in response', response);
          return response;
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        if (error.response && error.response.status === 400) {
          return error;
        }
        throw error;
      }),
};
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

BACKEND CODE

```
    username = request.json['data']['Username']
    password = request.json['data']['Password']

    try:
        u = Cognito(COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID, COGNITO_CLIENT_ID, username=username)
        u.authenticate(password=password)

        resp = make_success_resp({'username': u.username})
        # 31557600 sec in 1 year
        resp.set_cookie('ATOK',str(u.access_token),max_age=60*60*24*365*2, domain= 'app.localhost')
        resp.set_cookie('IDTOK', u.id_token)
        resp.set_cookie('RTOK', u.refresh_token)
        resp.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"]=True
        resp.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"]="*"
        return resp
    except ClientError as e:
        print(username + ": ", e.response['Error']['Message'])
        return make_err_resp(e.response['Error']['Message'], 400)
```

```
from flask_cors import CORS
CORS(app,origin='http://localhost:3000',credentials='true')
```

Comment: Kindly give use-case 26 in this [Github Repository](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/tree/master/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js) a whirl, and let me know if it helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming nothing is wrong with your code, I think it may be due to using localhost.  Try mapping a hostname to localhost in your hosts file and using that instead: `127.0.0.1 testsite.dev` and set the cookies for `http://testsite.dev:port`